# Comenzar la "cuenta" de un array con 1 y no con 0

Tags: javascript

El caso es que tengo el **script** hecho, el cual ejecuta un loop para generar una serie de frases. Quiero que la cuenta del **array** empiece por **0** y no por **1**, para que tenga sentido.

```
var colours = ["White", "Red", "Black", "Purple", "Grey", "Yellow", "Blue"];
var cities = ["Japan", "Korea", "Spain", "England", "China", "Singapur", 
"Rumania"];
var days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday"];

for (var n = 0; n < colours.length; n++) {
    document.write("My " + n + " choice is " + colours[n] + " in " + 
cities[n] + " on " + days[n] + "<br>");
}
```

Éste es el resultado que me da actualmente.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probablemente sea fácil pero no consigo verlo. Gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: ¿Será al revés no? Ya empieza por 0. Si es al revés simplemente: `'My ' + (n + 1) + 'blablabla'`

Comment: A qué te refieres con "Quiero que la cuenta del Array empiece por 0 y no por 1"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una opción es simplemente sumar 1 al valor de n únicamente para imprimir el valor desde 1 a n:

```js
var colours = ["White", "Red", "Black", "Purple", "Grey", "Yellow", "Blue"];
var cities = ["Japan", "Korea", "Spain", "England", "China", "Singapur", 
"Rumania"];
var days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday"];

for (var n = 0; n < colours.length; n++) {
    document.write("My " + (n + 1) + " choice is " + colours[n] + " in " + 
cities[n] + " on " + days[n] + "<br>");
}
```

o agregar una variable que funcione como contador que inicie desde 1:

```js
var colours = ["White", "Red", "Black", "Purple", "Grey", "Yellow", "Blue"];
var cities = ["Japan", "Korea", "Spain", "England", "China", "Singapur", 
"Rumania"];
var days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
"Saturday", "Sunday"];
var counter = 1;
for (var n = 0; n < colours.length; n++) {
    document.write("My " + counter + " choice is " + colours[n] + " in " + 
cities[n] + " on " + days[n] + "<br>");
 counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mmm si sólo quieres que aparezca en la cuenta, puedes usar:

```
 document.write("My " + (n+1) + " choice is " + colours[n] + " in " + cities[n] + " on " + days[n] + "<br>");
```

ya que si sólo lo pones ahí no afectará a las posiciones de tu array y aparecerá la cuenta incrementada después de "My".
Espero te sirva